# Auto Input when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, laravel

I need some help.

I have two form input and one checkbox, like this :

[image]

When the user insert **Address (Id Card)** and Check the checkbox below, then **Address(domicile) should be filled with the value same as address(id_card)**, form input in address (domicile) auto input same as in form input address (id card).

How to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: show some code so that someone can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tyr using `checkbox` `onclick` event.

```js
function copyAddress(e) {
  const checkboxValue = document.getElementById('copy-address').checked;
  if(checkboxValue) {
    document.getElementById('contact-address').value = document.getElementById('primary-address').value;
    document.getElementById('contact-address').disabled = true;
  }  else {
    document.getElementById('contact-address').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Address Details</h1>

<input type="text" id="primary-address" placeholder="Primary Address">
<label for="primary-address"> Primary Address</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="copy-address" name="copy" onclick="copyAddress(this)">
<label for="copy-address"> Copy address</label><br>

<input type="text" id="contact-address" placeholder="Contact Address">
<label for="contact-address"> Contact Address</label><br>
```

Comment: Thankyou, it's work in my code.
But if any form select dropdown dependent, it's not work

Answer (score 1):

I'd handle clicks on the checkbox. In the handler, I'd copy a value from one field to the other if it's checked and clear the 2nd address if it isn't.

```js
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
  byId('addrsAreSameCb').addEventListener('click', onAddrsAreSameCbClicked, false);
}

function onAddrsAreSameCbClicked(evt)
{
  if (this.checked == true)
  {
    byId('addr2').value = byId('addr1').value;
  }
  else
  {
    byId('addr2').value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='addr1'/><br>
<label><input type='checkbox' id='addrsAreSameCb'/>Addr 2 is same as Addr1</label></br>
<input id='addr2'/>
```